# DNS configuration : sub-domains pointing to different IP

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, subdomain

I would like to know if this type of domain and subdomain organisation for our school is feasable, and if so, how.

We have 2 different servers, say SERVER1 and SERVER2

SERVER1 is for school-critical applications: our website,and our extranet
SERVER2 is for each of our students and teachers 's websites. We plan to set Wordpress MU on it, so it will need a firstname.lastname.example.com

We want to work with only one Top Level Domain:  example.com and have as many subdomains as we have websites/webapps.

for instance, i figure our DNS record should look like this. But is this correct?

```
example.com  - public website (SERVER1) - webserver (A Record)
www.example.com - public website (SERVER1)  - webserver (A Record)
extranet.example.com  - Extranet (SERVER1)  - webserver (A Record)
old.example.com -silent redirects to SERVER2, old website. (A Record)
mail1.example.com - points to SERVER1, mailserver   (MX Record priority 10)
mail2.example.com  - points to SERVER2, mailserver   (MX Record priority 20)
```

// a wildcard redirects any other requests to SERVER2

```
*.example.com - points to SERVER2
```

Is this feasible? And how should SERVER2 be configured, dns-wise?

Answer (score 3):

This is entirely feasible. In bind, the wildcard line would look like this

```
*.example.com.        IN      A       1.2.3.4
```

Comment: thanks. So that i understand you right: if the TLD Domain is pointed to SERVER1, that's where the DNS Record containing all the redirects should be, correct? 
How should SERVER 2 be configured ? It's a completely different machine, in another datacenter by another provider. It will have a DNS Record on its own DNS server too ?
Thank you again for your time.

Comment: You do not need to run any DNS server on SERVER2. Just run wordpress on it. You will need to configure your web-server to do name-based virtual hosting though.

Comment: ... Wich means adding a virtualhost for each student account (firstname-lastname.domain.tld) , exact? That's what you mean ?

Comment: Or using the vhost_alias module in apache for bulk configuration, like you want in this case.